# How to validate an update cypher query against a schema?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a neo4j database and I want it to conform to a predefined schema (model).

This schema has some constraints like a node with label `x` should be related to a node with label `y` with relation type `r` only. No other relation between `x` and `y` is allowed. For example, only nodes labeled `:Person` can be at the two ends of a `:friend_of` relationship, but a node with label `:Object` cannot be at any end of the `:friend_of` relationship.

Another constraint can be what type of properties are allowed on a node having a particular label. For example a node with label `:Person` can only have properties name and age. No other property is allowed.

So I want to create a method which takes input an update cypher query and checks if it updates the database as per the existing schema or not. Assume that the schema exists in JSON or XML format.

Can someone guide me how can I go about solving the problem? Should I perhaps parse the query using CypherParser and then do something?

Comment: You're going to let your users do arbitrary queries on your database?

Comment: No, I am not going to let any arbitrary queries run on my database. @JanVandenbosch

Comment: Hum. My first thought is get a UI !
Second thought is that this makes an interesting issue. 
My propositions:
Creating a virtual graph then checking your rules on the nodes (if your queries are just adding content. 

Or pour everything in main graph, with a label saying 'unchecked' on the nodes then using this label in a sort of Cron batch (a homemade procedure that would do the checkings then remove the label). 
Also have a look at APOC user guide, you could find what suits your need.
Eventually, it may save you time to use a rule engine like drools because rules often pile up.